# How to generate pertinent text?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, nlp, probability-theory, gensim

What I want to do is, get a text training set (natural language) and increase this set with automatically created text that tries to mimic the text content. I'm using a bag-of-words assumption, sequence doesn't matter, syntax doesn't matter, I just want to create text that contains words that is pertinent with the general topic of the base.

Right now I'm using **Latent Dirichlet Allocation** to classify my documents in topics distributions, average the topic distribution of my set, and generate documents from these topic distribution.

I want to know two things:

> 1- Is there a better way to do that?
>
> 2- Can I train LDA with texts that are not of the domain of my set,
>   without tainting my topics: Eg. The set that I want to increase has
>   texts about politics. Can I train my model with any kind of text
>   (cars, fashion, musics) and classificates my base of politics text get its topics distributions and generates similar text from this distribution.

I'm using python 2.7 and gensim.

Comment: Your question feels way too vague to me. If you don't care about word ordering, you are just generating random collection of words which don't really make sense to humans that way sentences and paragraphs do. In this situation, how exactly do you evaluate pertinence? There either needs to be a more precise definition of pertinence available to us, or you need to tell us what you are doing with the word bags that you are generating, so that we can identify what is it that needs to be optimized.

Comment: You just need to generate a Markovian language model with n-grams, and then start choosing consecutive words randomly by calculating the highest probability of next words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NLTK's generate() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391602/what-does-generate-do-when-using-nltk-in-python) may be what you're looking for.

From [the docs](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=generate#nltk.text.Text.generate):

> `generate(length=100)`
>
> Print random text, generated using a
> trigram language model.
>
> Parameters:
>
> length (int) – The length of text to generate (default=100)