# Save any output a function gives, into a variable

Tags: python, variables

Being new at programming in general, and new with Python in particular, I'm having some beginner's troubles.

I'm trying out a function from NLTK called generate:

```
string.generate()
```

It returns what seems like a string. However, if I write:

```
stringvariable = string.generate()
```

or

```
stringvariable = str(string.generate())
```

… the stringvariable is always Empty.

So I guess I'm missing something here. Can the text output generated, that I see on the screen, be something else than a string output? And if so, is there any way for me to grab that output and put it into a variable?

Briefly put, how to I get what comes out of string.generate() into stringvariable, if not as described above?

Comment: There's not much information here to go on, so here are a few questions which would be helpful to know: (1) is it possible your `string.generate()` function is printing but not returning the string you're seeing? (2) Is there *something* in `stringvariable`? What do you see if you do `type(stringvariable)`?

Comment: First, `string` is a bad variable name because it shadows a builtin module. Second, most likely your sample corpus is too small.

Comment: It turns out the function prints the string rather than returning it. Not sure how to capture it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite generate.  The only disadvantage is that it can change and your code might not be updated to reflect these changes:

```
from nltk.util import tokenwrap
def generate_no_stdout(self, length=100):
    if '_trigram_model' not in self.__dict__:
        estimator = lambda fdist, bins: LidstoneProbDist(fdist, 0.2)
        self._trigram_model = NgramModel(3, self, estimator=estimator)
    text = self._trigram_model.generate(length)
    return tokenwrap(text)
```

then "a.generate()" becomes "generate_no_stdout(a)"

Answer (score 0):

`generate()` [prints its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391602/what-does-generate-do-when-using-nltk-in-python) rather than returning a string, so you need to [capture it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer).